# How can I sync data with external apps and SugarCRM?

Tags: sugarcrm

I have a client who would like to capture data from two third party systems and associate it with Sugar CRM user records.

One of the apps is a payment processor and the other is a mailing system (for confidentiality reasons I am not able to share what the apps are).

Both of these apps have no sugar CRM integration but they do have API's to allow data to be "pulled" out of them.

My client has been using sugar crm for quite some time now and has many contacts being tracked. They are hosting with sugarondemand.com

With the financial application they would like to keep track of how much revenue has been captured for each client (both a sum of total revenue and individual records of each transaction)

For the mailing system they would like to keep track of each email sent to each client. (So if the mailing list is 20,000 they would like to track which email was sent to all 20,000 users within sugar CRM.

I have some questions!

- Would the best approach be to build custom scripts on a third party server that pulls data from the payment processor and email service, and then pushes it to sugar CRM?
- If I do that would it be best to build a plugin for sugar CRM that might accept posted data or should I try to use existing cloud connectors?
- Should I keep their system on sugarondemand.com for this kind of problem or will I need to host sugarcrm on a custom server
- Any advice or ideas on how to deal with reconciliating 20,000 records in one go for mailout?

Thanks very much in advance for any help you may be able to offer.

Answer (score 3):

1. You can use both a custom workflow in sugar (which requires the pro. version) for pulling the data, or a third party tool/script to push, like you suggest. Personally I'd use a third party tool/script, and insert the data through sugar's SOAP API.
2. I'd recommend using the SOAP web services, which should be fine for the tasks you describe.
3. SugarOnDemand should be ok for what I described.

A simple suggestion is included below, but unfortunately I don't think you can create one email in Sugar and than link that to the 20.000 accounts. So you need to create the 20.000 emails in sugar and link them to the respective accounts. I filled in some of the web service calls in order to give you an idea of the functionalty.

More info is avaiable here: [Sugar SOAP documentation](https://www.sugarcrm.com/crm/support/documentation/SugarCommunityEdition/6.2/-docs-Developer_Guides-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.0-Sugar_Developer_Guide_6.2.1_html.html#9000398)

```
<?php   
    require_once('include/nusoap/lib/nusoap.php');

    // Connect to sugar
    $soapClient = new nusoap_client('http://mysite.com/soap.php?wsdl',true);
    $loginResult = $soapClient->call('login', array('user_auth' => array('user_name' => 'xxxx','password' => MD5('xxxx'),'version' => '0.1'), 'application_name' => 'myApp'));
    $sessionId = $loginResult['id'];

    // Connect to payment processing 
    // Retrieve transactions
    // Calculate sums for accounts
    // Retrieve account and id for accounts, e.g.
    $accountParams = array(
        'session' => $sessionId, 'module_name' => 'Accounts',
        'query' => "accounts.name = 'xxxxx'", 'order_by' => '', 'deleted' => 0
    );
    $accountId = $soapClient->call('get_entry_list', $accountParams)['id'];

    // Update accounts in sugar
    $updateParams = array(
        'session' => $sessionId, 'module_name' => 'Accounts',
        array(array('name'=>'id', 'value'=>$accountId),array('name'=>'value_to_update','value'=>$value))
    );
    $soapClient->call('set_entry', $updateParams);

    // Insert transaction and link to account

    // Connect to email system
    // Retrieve sent emails
    // Create email and link to the respective account

    // Disconnect from sugar
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would set up an integration process that was run regularly (probably via cron). Each time it runs it would use the APIs you mentioned, to ask for recent additions. It would then use web services to connect to Sugar to add the records.

You can avoid the web services into Sugar by putting the integration in Sugar's custom directory. From there you can call the various Sugar code directly, to add new records. This is really simple. As an example, if you were inserting Notes, you would have code something like this:

```
$note = new Note();

$note->name = $name;

$note->...     all the other fields you want to set

$note->save();
```

I hope that helps, even if it ids a very brief explanation.

Regards,
Greg Ambrose